# HGET always return NULL?

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis

I have some trouble, i have success insert new data into my redis
like this...

```
this.redisClient.hset("MySnapshot", myAccountId, JSON.stringify(Newsnapshot), (err: any, res: any) => {
    if (err) return callback(err, null);
    callback(null, res);
});
```

but when i want to get my data back, i use this code

```
client.hget("MySnapshot", myAccountId, (err: any, obj: any) => {
        if (err) {
          callback(err, null);
        } else {
          data = JSON.parse(obj);
        }
});
```

I still get null data until now (err and obj always null)...
But when i replace 'myAccountId' with some data i get from redis-cli, just like '123456789' that code success show data. It's something wrong with my code?
Can you help me.

Comment: what values does `myAccountId` hold?

Comment: DONE, i use promise to get the result, thanks for your respond